Packet loss in internal network
I am experiencing packet loss in my internal network. I have a Cisco-managed switch.
I have three physical servers with VMs running on them. The servers are connected to a switch with an Ethernet cable. It is configured in the 10.0.0.0/22 network.
After every 5 mins, there is a drop in the packets in the 10.0.0.0/22 network.
While pinging google DNS there is no drop in packets in the external network.
How can I fix this?


So everything on the local subnet is wired to the same switch? No Wi-Fi involved? If so, even when there's no packet loss, your latency is terrible. Single hop Ethernet latency should be below 1ms. Have you taken a packet capture to see if you have some kind of packet storm going on or something?

You say pinging Google DNS doesn't show drops but your screenshot shows a drop in the window that's pinging Google DNS. So maybe the off-subnet traffic isn't immune after all.
